# Using target to open another div but div doesn't show

Tags: html, css

I am using the target pseudo class so when the "Open" hyper link is clicked, it shows the `#content` div. However, when you click on the hyperlink, nothing happens.

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}

.btn:target #content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <a href="#content"><div class="btn">open</div></a>
    <div id="content">
    some content
    </div>
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: `:target` is a pseudo-selector to target the element that has been called with an anchor not an element within the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here

1st: `:target` is a pseudo-selector to select the targeted element. This means the element that the anchor refers to and not an element within the anchor.

2nd: You have a **specificity weight** issue. An `id` has the highest specificity and as such always overwrites other declarations with lower specificity even if written below.You can lower the specificity by using an attribute selector instead of the id selector:

```css
[id="content"] {
  display: none;
}

*:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#content"><div class="btn">open</div></a>
    <div id="content">
    some content
    </div>
```